# Looping this.props.children how do I test their type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In the following code snippet in a custom React component

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children), (child) => {
    if (predicate(child)) {
        // do stuff
    }
    else {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

`predicate` is a function that tests the child for certain properties or whatever.  **How can I write `predicate` to test what type of element a child is?**

In the article, [Send Props to Children in React](http://jaketrent.com/post/send-props-to-children-react/) you see the same pattern that I applied above, except his predicate function looks like `child.type === RadioOption.type` -- this doesn't work if I want to check against a type the child has inherited from.

In my case, I have `StatelessModal` -- `child` may be one of several different components that extends `StatelessModal`.

When I know that child is one of the Modal components that extends StatelessModal, I find that neither `predicate = (child) => child instanceof StatelessModal` nor `predicate = (child) => child.type instanceof StatelessModal` work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played around in the console and figured out this works:

```
predicate = (child) => child.type.prototype instanceof StatelessModal
```

While the `type` property of a `ReactElement` seems to be undocumented, it is reasonable to note that here, `child` is a `ReactElement`, and `child.type` is a `ComponentClass` (you may also find it may be a `string` or `StatelessComponent`) -- the ComponentClass is the class that defines the component; if the component was created through inheritance, the classes prototype chain includes the inherited type which is revealed by [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Comment: I've noticed that this sometimes breaks when using the React production build.

Answer (score 0):

The answer accepted not work for me at all.

I've test several ways to check children type. The conclusion comes that:

```
predicate = (child) => child.type === StatelessModal
```

Worked for both class components and functional components in react@16.7 and react@16.8 in both develop and production env.

Further test cases in https://github.com/dancerphil/react-children-type

And https://dancerphil.github.io/react-children-type/ shows the conclusion of production build.