# How Can I Check the Type (ie. instanceof) of a Redux Connect-ed Component?

Tags: reactjs

In this Stack Overflow question:

[Comparing two components - is Component X an instance of Component A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824548/comparing-two-components-is-component-x-an-instance-of-component-a)

Dan Abramov explains the correct way of determining whether a `child` variable is an instance of a `Foo` React class.  Because `return <Foo />` doesn't actually return an instance of `Foo`, you can't simply use `instanceof`; instead you have to do:

```
child.type === Foo.type
```

That's great, except that I'm using Dan's own library, Redux, and Redux instructs you to wrap your (store-using) components with it's `connect` function:

```
connect((a) => a)(
    class Foo extends React.Component { //...
)
```

Unfortunately, doing that changes the `.type` of Foo elements to the `connect` function itself:

```
const x = <Foo />;
console.log(x.type); // connect
```

So, my question is, is there any way I can figure out what React class an element came from if the React class in question used Redux's `connect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will pass `withRef = true` in `connect` options, as per the [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments), you can later use `x.getWrappedInstance().type` to figure out what React class an element came from.