# Conditionally pass props to child based on component type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to React and I'm creating a simple toolset of form fields which use react-bootstrap. I am using a `<Form>` component to wrap everything in. The `<Form>` component will render all the child children, passing a new property.

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
        myNewProp: 'hello'
    }
});
```

The problem I have is that the elements which are children which don't have a prop of `myNewProp` results in a warning `Unknown props myNewProp`, native HTML and react-bootstrap components. Is there any way to conditionally add props to the child element based upon the type of the component? E.g.

```
if (child instanceof <nativeHTMLelement>) { ... } else { ... }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two components - is Component X an instance of Component A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824548/comparing-two-components-is-component-x-an-instance-of-component-a)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `child.type` in this case:

```
if (typeof child.type === 'string') {
  // this is a html element
} else {
  // this is a React component
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I also added a check for `child.type.prototype instanceof MyElement`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `isNumber` and `isString`:

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
    if(!child)
        return child;
    if(isNumber(child))
        return child;
    if(isString(child))
        return child;
    // then this must be a ReactElement
    if(child.type === MyElement)
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
            myNewProp: 'hello'
        }
});
```

If you're using typescript, `isNumber` and `isString` should be provided by `@types/node`. If you are not they are easy enough to implement.